# Cordova Electron app, openFileDialog event

Tags: node.js, cordova, electron

In my app I open a new window with an external web pagte. This page let users to choose a file. I need to intercept the openFileDialog opened.

Is there a way to do this? 
Alternatively ss there a way to execute a script from the external page that runs some function on my electron app?

Thank you

Example:

```
            // open an external page
            const { remote } = require('electron');
            const { BrowserWindow } = remote;

            win = remote.getCurrentWindow();
            newWin = new BrowserWindow(
                {
                    parent: win,
                    modal: false,
                    show: false,
                    width: 1280,
                    height: 1024,
                    webPreferences: {
                        nodeIntegration: false,
                        plugins: true
                    }
                }
            );
            newWin.loadURL(url);

            //Page into newWin will open a file choose dialog and i need to know this is happened...
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried electron [dialog](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog), below code snippet uses a same electron thread

```
const { dialog } = require('electron')
console.log(dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections'] }))
```

To exchange information between process you may look into 
[ipc-main](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) AND [webContents](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-arg1-arg2-)

Comment: The problem is it's not me to open the dialog, Dialog is opened by the webpage inside newWIn (not node).

Comment: Yes, this can be a way if possibile

Comment: yes it is possible i just updated answer with comments

Comment: Ok but, i need to send an event from my website (inside newWin browserWindow). Maybe I don't understand your suggestion but i nedd to know that newWin has opened an openDialog window or a button is clicked...

Comment: Note: my website is opened without node integration and needs to be disabled...